# Changing values in a range of columns using R

Tags: r

I'm trying to change certain column's values using something like this:

This works fine:

```
DF[,(6:12)][DF[,(6:12)]!=""]<- 13
```

This throws an error:

```
DF[,(6:12,23:25)][DF[,(6:12:23:25)]!=""]<- 13

Error: unexpected ','
```

Why?  How can I specify multiple ranges here?

Comment: try `c(6:12,23:25)`

Comment: Do you want to replace all instances of  "" or NA? By the way "" is a character not a numeric.